# How to read data from google sheets using google api and save to laravel database

Tags: php, laravel, google-sheets, laravel-8

I have to read data from google sheets using google api and save to laravel database. I am beginner in laravel, so their is a request to elaborate it well. Thanks for effort.

I tried few ways but I am not getting the results.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [kawax/laravel-google-sheets](https://github.com/kawax/laravel-google-sheets) package.

Comment: And tutorial https://drivemarketing.ca/en/blog/connecting-laravel-to-a-google-sheet/